# function for Sequence Generator between Columns

Tags: r

I wrote a function `my_fun` to generate sequences between columns, but I don't like it, it's cumbersome and slow. Can you show me a more correct way to write `my_fun`?

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(30, sd = 0.05)
x2 <- x1+0.2+rnorm(30,sd = 0.05)

# some data for example
X <- cbind.data.frame(x1,x2)
matplot(X,t="l",lty=1)


my_fun <- function(X, by=0.01){
res <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
  res <- rbind.data.frame(
                          res,
                          cbind(idx=i,val=seq(X$x1[i],X$x2[i], by=by))
                         )}
res
}

res <- my_fun(X)
print( res )
points(res, col=8)
```

The function is quite simple, so I’m not sure if it’s necessary to explain what it does, to understand it, just run the code, I also added plots for visualization

---

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   my_fun(X),
+   my_fun2(X),
+   ThomasIsCoding_fun(X),
+   jblood94_fun(X), times = 5)
Unit: microseconds
                  expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
             my_fun(X) 13445.3 13603.4 13787.20 13797.9 13860.3 14229.1     5
            my_fun2(X)  2214.9  2297.2  4754.70  2407.0  2447.9 14406.5     5
 ThomasIsCoding_fun(X)  5510.8  5728.3 12882.36  6036.4 17120.4 30015.9     5
       jblood94_fun(X)   680.0   750.3  3900.88   764.8   814.3 16495.0     5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vectorized version using `rep.int` and `sequence`:

```
my_fun_vec <- function(X, by = 0.01) {
  n <- (X[,2] - X[,1])/by + 1
  data.frame(idx = rep.int(1:length(n), n),
             val = rep.int(X[,1], n) + sequence(n, X[,1])*by)
}
```

Testing:

```
res2 <- my_fun_vec(X)

all.equal(res, res2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is a very fast function! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `Map` + `seq`

```
my_fun_vec <- function(X, by = 0.01) {
    setNames(
        type.convert(
            stack(setNames(Map(seq, X$x1, X$x2, by = by), 1:nrow(X)))[2:1],
            as.is = TRUE
        ),
        c("idx", "val")
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there may also be such a function

```
my_fun2 <- function(X, by=0.01) {
 lapply(1:nrow(X), \(i)  cbind(idx=i,val=seq(X$x1[i],X$x2[i], by=by))) |> 
    do.call(what = rbind)
}
```